# how to capture natives events in netbeans using logging

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/doc-files/logging.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("your.package.Log");
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {        
        LogRecord r = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "MSG_Add");
        r.setResourceBundle(rb);
        r.setParameters(new Object[] { sum, i });
        Logger.global.log(r);
        sum += i;
    }        
    LogRecord r = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "MSG_Result");
    r.setResourceBundle(rb);
    r.setParameters(new Object[] { sum });
    Logger.global.log(r);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Logger.global` is deprecated. If you change the logger lines to (change `<YOUR CLASS>` to the name of your class, obviously)

```
Logger.getLogger(<YOUR CLASS>.class.getName()).log(r);
```

Then the logged lines will appear in NetBeans' Output tab